# function javascript doesn't read xml file

Tags: javascript, xml

```
function getName(fname, text)

{
var xmlFile = "piante.xml"; 
var xmlDoc;

if(typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET",xmlFile,false);
    if (xmlhttp.overrideMimeType){
        xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
    }
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
}
else{

    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async="false";
    xmlDoc.load(xmlFile);
}

var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROW");
document.write(x.length);

for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){ 

  var y=x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATA");

  if(y[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue == text){
      var z= y[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

      return z;}

     }
}
```

here my file .xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<FMPXMLRESULT
xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult"><ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE><PRODUCT
BUILD="12-06-2016" NAME="FileMaker" VERSION="ProAdvanced 15.0.3"/><DATABASE
DATEFORMAT="D/m/yyyy" LAYOUT="" NAME="IndexHorti v3.12.fmp12" RECORDS="586"
TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss "/>

<METADATA><FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Gen Spe con spazio"
TYPE="TEXT"/><FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Localizzazione esemplare LAST"
TYPE="TEXT"/><FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Link WEB"
TYPE="TEXT"/></METADATA>

<RESULTSET FOUND="2">

<ROW MODID="56" RECORDID="20055">
<COL><DATA>Acanthus  mollisL.</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>01-02-01-23</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>www.corriere.it</DATA></COL></ROW>

<ROW MODID="12" RECORDID="20057">
<COL><DATA>Achillea  millefolium L.</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>01-05-01-16</DATA></COL>
<COL><DATA>www.repubblica.it</DATA></COL></ROW>
</RESULTSET>
</FMPXMLRESULT>
```

launching this script nothing appears!!!please help me. I put fie piante.xml in the same folder of this script. here the page that test my script if you click on the circle.

http://www.soluzioniwebdesign.it/provaRubini/

thank u

Comment: Insert some console.log or alert statements to get feedback on the JavaScript processing. Remove or comment these statements out once the problems have been identified and resolved.

Comment: I tried but nothing appears

Comment: Check the console for errors, I see a GET /provaRubini/piante.xml 404 (Not Found)

Comment: solved!!! here the right code

Answer (score 0):

```
function getName(fname, text)

{
    var fname ="piante.xml";
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xhttp.open("GET",fname,false);
                xhttp.send();

                xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;





var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ROW");

for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){ 

  var y=x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATA");

  if(y[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue == text){

      var z= y[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

      return z;}

     }
}
```

here the right code...maybe it could help